# Discord.js Arguments With Spaces

Tags: javascript, bots, discord, discord.js

So I'm trying to create my bot and I want there to be a command which adds information to a sqlite database

https://gyazo.com/6961a05dc2d6aeca6683b59f888c2e82

```
if (command === "addplayer") {
  message.delete()
  let [name, crew, rank, weapon, df, talent, profession, other] = args;
  if(!name) return message.author.send("Name argument is required!");
  let id = name.toLowerCase();
  if(!crew) {let crew = "Blank";}
  if(!rank) {let rank = "Blank";}
  if(!weapon) {let weapon = "Blank";}
  if(!df) {let df = "Blank";}
  if(!talent) {let talent = "Blank";}
  if(!profession) {let profession = "Blank";}
  if(!other) {let other = "Blank";}

  sql.run("INSERT INTO players (id, Name, Crew, Rank, Weapon, DF, 
Talent, Profession, Other) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)", [id, 
name, crew, rank, weapon, df, talent, profession, other]);
  return
}
```

All I want to know really is how to add like a space key to the arguments so I can do

`>addplayer info with space, more info, even more, and so on`

And when I do the other command it lists it out like this:

`Info1: info with space
Info2: more info
Info3: even more
Info4: and so on`

Comment: Sounds like you want to pick up a variable from each line input. I'm not experienced at all in sql but I will do my best to work out an answer for you, also wouldn't it be easier to make it so commands are separate? like: `!captain nameOfCaptain` etc.

Comment: i guess that is what i wanted but is it possible to make it one command?

Comment: I'm sure it is, not that I know exactly how to, but you might be better off having each separate command define `crew` `rank` `weapons` etc. then have a command that displays all of them like in the screenshot

Comment: In your 1 command, do you want the arguments to be separated by spaces or by commas? Your final comment (after "And when I do the other command...") makes it sound like you want arguments to be delimited by comma.

Comment: @BlunderingPhilosopher yes that is what i would like so you do
`>player info 1, some more info, and so on`

Comment: @jimmybenoit so what would a full, real example command look like?

Comment: @BlunderingPhilosopher a full example of the command would be

`>addplayer jimmybenoit, Example Crew, Captain, Example Longsword, Example Fruit, Gainer, Cook, Other Information Goes here`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've just decided to go with multiple commands like

`>edit EXAMPLE`
and then doing something like

`>editname EXAMPLE1` setting the name to EXAMPLE1 instead of EXAMPLE

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so using your sample command as an example, let's say someone enters this, and you want to know how to handle it:

> >addplayer jimmybenoit, Example Crew, Captain, Example Longsword, Example Fruit, Gainer, Cook, Other Information Goes here

I assume you have already figured out how to check the command prefix, and split the command from the args, but I'll show how I would do that below.

```
// get message content from user
let input = message.content;

// get command prefix ">"
//  -> probably check that this is valid, if you haven't done that already
let prefix = input[0];

// get command (1 word)
let command = input.substr(1).split(' ')[0];

// get args - looks like you've already done this
let args = command.substr( command.indexOf(' ') + 1 );

// Check if command is valid, as you have in your code
if (command === "addplayer") {
    // split args into an array, comma delimited
    // -> also map .trim() function to remove beginning / ending spaces
    args = args.split(',').map(elem => elem.trim());

    // split args into vars
    let [name, crew, rank, weapon, df, talent, profession, ...other] = args;

    // .. do the rest of your code
}
```

The key here, is you use `.split(',')` to turn the args string into an array, split on `','` character (and use `.trim()` to clear out whitespace from each element, THEN you assign all of your variables to the args array.

The final `...other]` is used to catch any remaining arguments - so if your text `'Other information Goes here'` had commas, all of those extra arguments would get stored (as an array) in the `other` variable. If you want to put them all back together, you can use `.join(',')` to separate them by comma.

Let me know if you have any questions!

Comment: so when you are doing the command it is split on , instead of space because if so that is what i needed

Comment: args = args.split(',').map(elem => elem.trim());
              ^

TypeError: args.split is not a function

Comment: `args.split` only works when `args` is a string, as it is in my code above. Are you settings `args` like I did?

Comment: are there any other ways I can do this?

Answer (score 0):

You can also do this:

```
var arguments = args.toString();
arguments = arguments.split(",,").join(";")
arguments = arguments.split(",").join(" ")
arguments = arguments.split(";").join(",")
arguments = arguments.split(',');
```