# discord.js - I need help for a profile command

Tags: javascript, discord.js

So, I've created a profile command for my bot but I wanna add an second argument.
The command that I wanna make is "/profile [username to search]" , but I don't now how to do it.

If you can help me, I'll appreciate this.

Here is the code:

```
if (message.content === '/profile') {
      let botembed = new Discord.RichEmbed()
                .setTitle("**__Exoly User Profile__**")
                .setTimestamp(new Date())
                .setColor("#4286f4")
                .setFooter("Exolia", `${bot.user.avatarURL}`)
                .setThumbnail(`${message.author.avatarURL}`)
                .addField("Username :", `${message.author.username}`, inline = true)
                .addField("Exolytes :", "|---|", inline = true)
                .addField("Played Time :", "|---|", inline = true)
                .addField("Faction :", "Armada", inline = true);
       if (shouldResponseTo(message)) {
           message.delete()
           return message.channel.send(botembed);
       }
    }
```

Comment: It's worth adding what code you have already so there's a something to reference from

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Discord.js Arguments With Spaces](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49021540/discord-js-arguments-with-spaces)

Answer (score 0):

A quick nice way to do what you want,

```
//Checks if it starts with (/profile) 
if(message.content.startsWith(`/profile`)){
    //Defines the user that needs to be searched to be either the user pinged OR the user that called the command
    let user = message.mentions.users.first(); || message.author;
    let embed = new Discord.RichEmbed()
    .setTitle(`Profile`);
    .setDescription(`Profile of ${user.username}`);
    //Note: .send(embed) is allowed but not recommended and it's easier and safer todo .send({embed}) or in your case .send({embed:botembed})
    message.channel.send({embed});    
}
```

You could also check what was said AFTER `(/profile)` by doing:

```
let args = message.content.split(` `);
if(args[0]===`/profile`){
    args.shift();
    //args is now all the arguments that was put in after (/profile)

    //So a message (/profile @user page 3)
    //args would equal ["@user", "page", "3"]

}
```